# How to get PodName and PodIp through the deployment.yml file in Asp .net core MVC?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, kubernetes, asp.net-web-api, minikube

I have a two projects Asp .net core Api and Asp .net core MVC.

In Api Project, this is my Deployment.yml code :

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
  name: webapiservice2
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: product-app
 spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: webapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: product-app
        service: webapi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: webapiservice2
          image: ommkwn/webapiservice2:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          args:
            - while true; do
              echo sync app logs;
              printenv POD_NAME POD_IP POD_SERVICE_ASCCOUNT;
              sleep 20;
              done;
          env:
           - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
             value: http://+:80
           - name: POD_NAME
             valueFrom:
               fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
           - name: POD_IP
             valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
               fieldPath: status.podIP
           - name: POD_SERVICE_ASCCOUNT
             valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
```

in this deployment.yml file this "ASPNETCORE_URLS" name value are printed successfully but the "POD_NAME", "POD_IP" , "POD_SERVICE_ASCCOUNT" are not printed when i run the Asp .net core MVC project

my Asp .net core MVC code :

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger ,IConfiguration configuration)
        {
           
            _logger = logger;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetMySqlData()
        {

            var podName = _configuration["POD_NAME"];
            var podIP = _configuration["POD_IP"];
            var podServiceAccount = _configuration["POD_SERVICE_ASCCOUNT"];
            var newurls = _configuration["ASPNETCORE_URLS"];


            ViewBag.podName = podName;
            ViewBag.podIp = podIP;
            ViewBag.podServiceAccount = podServiceAccount;
            ViewBag.newurls = newurls;

            var Baseurl = "http://webapiservice2-0.default.svc.cluster.local:8081";

            List<Customer> EmpInfo = new List<Customer>();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Passing service base url  
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

                //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("/home/mysqldata");

                //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                    var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                    EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(EmpResponse);

                }
                //returning the employee list to view  
                return View(EmpInfo);

            }

            
        }

    }
```

when i see with this command in kubernets "kubectl describe pod webapiservice2-f6d9d7bfb-4xvkv" there are all "POD_NAME" , "POD_IP", "POD_SERVICE_ASCCOUNT" and "ASPNETCORE_URLS" are get successfully.

like this:

[image]

So how to "POD_NAME" , "POD_IP", "POD_SERVICE_ASCCOUNT" are print on the MVC view